# What is a common way to address someone using 'call' without the overtones of 'call by phone?'

Tags: idiom-requests

> Hi! It's Tom, the boy who sits behind you. You don’t know me because I’ve
>   never **called you** or poked your back.

**'called you'** sounds as if Tom is talking about calling the other person by phone.

What's a common way of phrasing this statement, meaning "to get her/his attention" without the **'call by phone'** overtones?

Comment: 'I've never spoken to you'?

Comment: Can you tell us what kind of definition you are looking for? Something that says you've never said her name to get her attention? Like spoken to her?

Comment: @Hank Yes, that's it. To get her/his attention.

Comment: I think 'spoken' is the right term, however, in the informal tone of the sentence,  I think "I've never said a thing to you" would fit the dialogue better.

Comment: I've never "gotten in touch with you" covers phone, email, social media, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can phrase Tom's ice-breaker like so:

> Hi! It's Tom, the boy who sits behind you [*in class*]. You probably don't know me, because I've never **called out to you** [*during recess /at the cafeteria*] or poked your back.

You can also check out [this](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/call+out) list containing some of the idiom's other meanings, just so that Tom does not accidentally call the other person he's addressing out to a duel.